# Need help making a File Export function remember the path that the user selects

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, web-applications

I have a function in my program that exports data. The exporting works great, but I'm having trouble with something: When the user clicks Export, they are presented with a folder browser to choose where on their hard drive they would like to export to. The browser launches *initially* with all the hard drives/folders collapsed like they should be, but I can't figure out how to make it so the program remembers which location the user chose, so that the next time they want to export, it automatically opens to that location instead of once again opening with everything collapsed. I'm just having trouble with the logic, I suppose. Anyone have any tips?

Also, just for clarification, I'm trying to get it to remember the location only for the duration of the session, not like permanently on the register.

Here's my export function so far, if you think that would be helpful:

```
private void Export(int formatVersion, bool pureXmlDriver)
{
  if (Device != null)
  {
    Utilities.StripShortNameFromLongNames(Device);

    using (var folderBrowser = new FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
      folderBrowser.Description = Resources.SelectExportFolder;

      if (folderBrowser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
        string selectedFolder = folderBrowser.SelectedPath;

        try
        {
          Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

          HandleExport(formatVersion, pureXmlDriver, selectedFolder);
        }
        finally
        {
          Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just set the initially select path, `folderBrowser.SelectedPath = selectedFolder`.

Comment: @jac Where would I put that, though? I can't put it before my folderBrowser.ShowDialog(), because it wouldn't have been initialized yet, correct? Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @Raymond No, the object is initialized when you `new` it. You are already setting the `Description` property; there's no reason why you can't set `SelectedPath`, too. You do need to cache the `selectedPath` somewhere from the previous export, however.

Comment: If your selectedPath has not been initialized you can give it a default value, the current program path, or leave it blank. The question sounded as though the user had already selected a folder at least once, and you wanted to open the dialog to their last selection. Maybe you're asking how to keep the value of the selected path? If that's the problem, make it a field level variable in your class.

Comment: @jac Yeah, I suck at explaining myself. Sorry about that. Here's what I want: User clicks Export for the first time in a session, folder browser doesn't default to anywhere, user chooses where they want to export to, the chosen location is remembered so that if they click Export again in the session, the folder browser defaults to the location chosen previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. You just need a class field to keep the last value in.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string selectedPath = "";

    public void Export(int formatVersion, bool pureXmlDriver)
    {
        if (Device != null)
        {
            Utilities.StripShortNameFromLongNames(Device);
            using (var folderBrowser = new FolderBrowserDialog())
           {
               folderBrowser.Description = Resources.SelectExportFolder;
               folderBrowser.SelectedPath = selectedPath;
               if (folderBrowser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
               {
                   selectedFolder = folderBrowser.SelectedPath;
                   try
                   {
                       Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                       HandleExport(formatVersion, pureXmlDriver, selectedFolder);
                   }
                   finally
                   {
                       Cursor = Cursors.Default;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }    
}
```